# Misconceptions on Electronics and circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage

So i had a question regarding basic circuits

1. What do negative currents and voltages mean.? This really stumped me for a while as negative current and voltage seemed odd to me if someone can clarify much appreciated.

p.s Sorry didn't realise there was too many questions asked before that were too broad, so i just edited it to include just this one as its the one that stumped me the most in class.

Comment: #3 sounds like a direct short. Which would either drain the battery very fast or burn the wire to the point where pops like a fuse.

Comment: Please do not ask so many different questions at once - ask *one question per post* so that each can be answered separately, unless they are so closely related they do not make sense as questions on their own.

Comment: if possible, you should try to ask one question at a time instead of writing a list of questions,

Comment: Oh ye i see what you mean , i guess i kinda got carried away asking too many at once each being different. I modified the post to include just the one i had trouble the most comprehending

Comment: Negative current means current into the opposite direction. Also negative voltage. In every circuit, you have an arrow next to all wires. If the current flows into the opposite direction, the potential elevates into the opposite direction, then it is negative. It doesn't matter in which direction you have the arrows, you will get the same result if you calculate with the currents (the formulas describing them also depend from the direction of the arrows).

Answer (score 3):

1. Power dissipated in a resistor $R$ is $I^2R$
2. Positive charges can also contribute to the current in gasses. Only electrons can move in a solid conductor.
3. What do you mean by '*just a wire*'. Does your wire have resistance?
4. Yes, A is at a higher electric potential than B. It's the result of chemical reactions inside the Battery. 
   Batteries. Batteries use a chemical reaction to do work on charge and produce a voltage between their output terminals. The basic element is called an electrochemical cell and makes use of an oxidation/reduction reaction. An electrochemical cell which produces an external current is called a voltaic cell.
   Batteries - Hyperphysics
5. Power is Joules/sec. $VI$ is indeed $Js^{-1}$.
6. Directions of currents and voltage differences are sign sensitive. If $V_A-V_B is +10V$ then $V_B-V_A = -10V$

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please use mathjax to format mathematical expressions. To learn more about mathjax, please read [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).